# Passing session information in stored procedure in code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using entity framework 5. Database first with importing stored procedures (most are Create, Update, Delete).

And currently i need to pass to most of procedures additional parameter user id.

I feel uncomfortable to use generated by EF procedures directly (like, `dbContext.UpdateEntity(userid, param1, param2, ...)`), because in some table there are more than 30 fields. There should be a better way - where should i search?

Maybe important in project i have edmx file - and i want to keep it this way, because of frequent updates.

Comment: Is that userId used in select queries? or only on insert/update/delete?

Comment: In all queries (but not on all tables). I'm good to use select queries through stored procedure import. But using others directly as they generated a little bit hard.